# Console's distinction implied by lower vs upper case in "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, object, console, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects

I've found no reference to this subtle, yet seemingly consequential, distinction. My question is about the console's capitalization of Object vs object.

For instance:

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}
var bob = new Person("Bob");

console.log(bob.name); // Bob --as desired.
```

However,

```
console.log(bob); // [object Object]
```

My question is not so much about my code's logic, but rather about the console's message.

What is the difference implied by the use of upper & lower case in these two words "object" and "Object"?

An answer to this may enable me and others to have a firm grasp of what console is trying to indicate.

Comment: It's not the console that does that formatting (indeed, in Chrome I would expect `console.log(bob)` to show something like *`Person {name: "Bob"}`*). The `"[object Object]"` thing is a result of `(someObject).toString()`...though your question about the capitalisation still applies. I believe it is indicating that you have an "object" of type `Object`, as compared to seeing the string `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` for an object of *that* type...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your `bob` object is being cast to a string via the `toString` method, which is defined by the ES6 specification as follows:

**[ES6: Object.prototype.toString ( ):](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)**

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the **this** value is **undefined**, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the **this** value is **null**, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let *O* be ToObject(**this** value).
> 4. Let *isArray* be IsArray(*O*).
> 5. ReturnIfAbrupt(*isArray*).
> 6. If *isArray* is **true**, let *builtinTag* be `"Array"`.
> 7. Else, if *O* is an exotic String object, let *builtinTag* be `"String"`.
> 8. Else, if *O* has an [[ParameterMap]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"Arguments"`.
> 9. Else, if *O* has a [[Call]] internal method, let *builtinTag* be `"Function"`.
> 10. Else, if *O* has an [[ErrorData]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"Error"`.
> 11. Else, if *O* has a [[BooleanData]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"Boolean"`.
> 12. Else, if *O* has a [[NumberData]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"Number"`.
> 13. Else, if *O* has a [[DateValue]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"Date"`.
> 14. Else, if *O* has a [[RegExpMatcher]] internal slot, let *builtinTag* be `"RegExp"`.
> 15. Else, let *builtinTag* be `"Object"`.
> 16. Let *tag* be Get (*O*, @@toStringTag).
> 17. ReturnIfAbrupt(*tag*).
> 18. If Type(*tag*) is not String, let *tag* be *builtinTag*.
> 19. Return the String that is the result of concatenating `"[object "`, *tag*, and `"]"`.

Basically, the spec says create a string like the following: `"[object " + InternalClassName + "]"` where `InternalClassName` is the native constructor for the object, `Object` in your case. The first is lowercase because the spec says use that string, the second is uppercase because that is the name of the native constructor.

Comment: I'll need to give this a think in order to truly absorb it. Very **interesting** thank you!